# Only digits, the digit may be decimal (regular expression)

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

in my web application i want to validate that user can enter only digits and the digit may be a integer or decimal how can i write the regular expression for this. help me thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpressionValidator` and here is Validation Expression `ValidationExpression="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"`

Finally it will be look like...

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgx" ControlToValidate="txtControl" runat="server"
      ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: ya thank you Mr.Muhammad Akhtar it is working fine. i have a doubt if i want only two digit after point like (120.33) how can i write the expression

Comment: ya Mr. Muhammad i got it i write like this [0-9]*\.?[0-9]{1,2} it is working it takes only two digits after the point. i am so happy

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a RangeValidation as an alternative? This may not meet your requirements but it does give you the ability to specify the input type you are expecting which could be any one of string, integer, double, date or currency. Choosing double or currency and setting the MinimumValue and MaximumValue properties to values which meet your input requirements may do the trick.